# Do not apply filter if sent to specific email address or contains specific word

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have the following gmail filter which is currently working

```
Matches: to:(-{nick@email.com nick2@email.com}) label:label1
Do this: Skip Inbox
```

I'd like to modify it to not have it run on emails that contain word1 OR word 2. So if an email has word1 OR word2 OR is sent to nick@email.com OR is sent to nick2@email.com then it would not run.